# S3 putObject callback not returning expected objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I want to get the link of the file (or file name is also fine) after I uploaded my image to S3. I upload using below code and it worked.

```
s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
        if (err) { 
          console.log(err);
          res.send({result:0});
        } else {
          res.send({result:1});
          console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

But in the callback data it has only 1 property, the etag. In the doc it clearly stated it has other object, so how do I get the path of the uploaded file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) don't imply that the object key will be available in the `data` callback parameter.

You can work out the S3 URI of the created object based on the bucket's name and the `params.Key` property on the request data.

Here's an example of how to do that from within the `putObject` callback

```
s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data) {
  var params = this.request.params;
  var region = this.request.httpRequest.region;
  console.log('s3://' + params.Bucket + '/' + params.Key);
  console.log('https://s3-' + region + '.amazonaws.com/' + params.Bucket + '/' + params.Key)
});
```

Comment: this url will always be so? there will be some way to get the url (NOT signed) from the sdk?